# Count a register between dates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table of courses (name, start_date, end_date) and I need to count each course for every year between start and end date.

For example, having a sample like this:

```
| name | start_date | end_date   |
----------------------------------
| c1   | 2019-01-01 | 2022-12-01 |
| c2   | 2020-01-01 | 2025-12-01 |
| c3   | 2018-01-01 | 2022-12-01 |
```

I need to return how many courses were active over the years, something like this:

```
| year | count_courses |
| 2018 | 1             | 
| 2019 | 2             | 
| 2020 | 3             | 
| 2021 | 3             |
| 2022 | 3             |
| 2023 | 1             | 
| 2024 | 1             |
| 2025 | 1             |
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Generate the years and then use some sort of aggregation.  Such as:

```
select gs.yyyy, count(s.start_date)
from generate_series('2018-01-01'::date,
                     '2025-01-01'::date,
                     interval '1 year'
                    ) gs(yyyy) left join
     sample s
     on s.start_date <= gs.yyyy and
        s.end_date > gs.yyyy
group by gs.yyyy;
```

This counts the number that are active on Jan 1st, which seems to be consistent with what you are asking.